# Is there a way to remove trailing 0's from TimeSpan.Parse

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

I have a Timespan that is HH:mm:ss.fffffff e.g. 12:13:08.1265838 and I use this code to format the Timespan to one decimal place:

```
Duration = TimeSpan.Parse(stopEventOut.StopEventDateTime.Subtract(stopEventIn.StopEventDateTime).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'f")),
```

This format the code to one decimal place but leaves trailing 0's. *(using the example above would format to 12:13:08.1000000)*

Is there a way to remove these in the to string formatting, or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be subtracting two datetimes to produce a `TimeSpan`, then calling `.ToString()` to format the result, and then redundantly parsing the result back to a `TimeSpan` again. So you format the string of the internal timespan (`12:13:08.1265838`) to  `"12:13:08.1"` and then parse it back to a `TimeSpan`, where it becomes `12:13:08.1000000`.

You should instead format *after* you're done with all the timespan calculations, and get rid of the redundant parsing:

```
Duration = stopEventOut.StopEventDateTime.Subtract(stopEventIn.StopEventDateTime),

// ... 

Console.WriteLine(Duration.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'f")); // 12:13:08.1
```

As a small bonus, you could create some extension methods on `TimeSpan` to format your timespans accordingly like so:

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{ 
    public static string WithTenthsOfASecond(this TimeSpan t)
    {
        return t.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'f");
    } 

    public static string WithHundredthsOfASecond(this TimeSpan t)
    {
        return t.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'ff");
    } 

    public static string WithMilliseconds(this TimeSpan t)
    {
        return t.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'fff");
    } 
}
```

Which then allows you to do:

```
Duration.WithTenthsOfASecond(); // "12:13:08.1"
Duration.WithHundredthsOfASecond(); // "12:13:08.12"
Duration.WithMilliseconds(); // "12:13:08.126"
```

Comment: is there a way to maintain it as a TimeSpan as that is what the model requires it to be?

Comment: @SJ_Dev `DateTime.Subtract(DateTime)` returns a TimeSpan. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-subtract(system-datetime)

Comment: @gunr2171 but it will be an unformatted timespan, with too many decimal places, e.g. 12:13:08.1265838, the spec is for 1 d.p.

Comment: A TimeSpan doesn't have a format. If you're viewing the value in a debugger it will look different than when you call `.ToString()`.

Comment: @SJ_Dev the TimeSpan has to be formatted to a string for presentation purposes. You can hide all your formatting methods by creating some extension methods on TimeSpan, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `f`, use `F`. That won't display any trailing `0`s.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#F_Specifier

Also if you are viewing `Duration` in the debugger - there's a default format.